# Subscripting sqlalchemy table columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a class that will look for certain column types in a sqlalchemy reflected table and then do some operations for a subset of columns based on the data type.

I can correctly reflect the table and grab a list of the 'date' type columns as shown in the date_types list.  However, when it gets to `table[name]` the function fails with the error:

```
*** TypeError: 'DeclarativeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

If I use dot subscripts instead of square brackets i.e. `table.col_name` I can access the table column attribute but I don't see how I would iterate over the attribute list using that syntax.

Here is my class:

```
from pdb import set_trace
class dateRangeProfiler():
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.date_ranges = {}
        self.date_types = [Date(), DateTime(), TIMESTAMP()]
        self.session = session
        print('date data types: ', str(self.date_types))
    def __call__(self, table):
        date_columns = self.getDateColumns(table)
        print(date_columns)
        date_column_profile = self.profileColumns(table, date_columns)
        return date_column_profile
    def getDateColumns(self, table):
        columns = [(c.name, c.type) for c in table.__table__.columns if str(c.type) in [str(dt) for dt in self.date_types]]
        return columns
    def profileColumns(self, table, date_cols):
        profile = {}
        for (name, _) in date_cols:
            set_trace()
            print(name)
            qry = self.session.query(func.max(table[name]).label("max_date"), 
                func.min(testTable[name]).label("min_date"),) # <-- fails here
            res = qry.one()
            max = res.max_date
            min = res.min_date
            profile.append({name: {'max':max, 'min':min}})
```

Here is how I call the profiler:

```
date_range_profiler = dateRangeProfiler(sess)
date_range_profiler(my_table)
```

And the error:

```
*** TypeError: 'DeclarativeMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't have anything to do with the sqlalchemy module.  When accesing attributes of object using variable references, use the `getattr()` base python function.

```
qry = self.session.query(func.max(getattr(table,name)).label("max_date"),
    func.min(getattr(table,name)).label("min_date"),)
```